# Spring RestController upload List of object containg MultipartFile object from mobile app

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I want to create rest API in Spring while will be used to upload gallery images at once. Below is my Gallery Pojo.

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

public class Gallery {

    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private MultipartFile file;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public MultipartFile getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(MultipartFile file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

}
```

In my Spring RestController I'm accepting `List<Gallery>` object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/gallery-images-save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Response saveGalleryImages(List<Gallery> galleryImages) {
    // my code to process and save gallery images.  
}
```

I found one solution but there Multipart array is accepted as request data.

like. `List<MultipartFile>` but in my scenario i want `List<Gallery>` where Gallery contains one single `MultipartFile` object.

Comment: Did you able to find any solution?

Comment: Yes. First of all use one wrapper class which will have a `List<Gallery>`. Then You have to give name attribute in array form example - `name='title[0]'` etc.